# Rails: Controller can not find method in according helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Controllers
 -concerns
   -application_controller.rb
   -display_controller.rb

Helpers
 -application_helper.rb
 -display_controller.rb
```

In display_helper.rb

```
   module DisplayHelper
        def is_c
          a + b
        end
    end
```

In display_controller.rb

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper
    include DisplayHelper

    def update
      @c = is_c
    end

end
```

The problem is if I want `@c = is_c` in update action work , I must do `include DisplayHelper` in Controller, otherwise the result of is_c can not be assigned to @c. Normally method in helper file can be used in accroding controller without including, but for this resource, why it does not work ?

Comment: helpers are for views if you need to include this in a controller than `include` or `helper` methods are available for that. That being said I am not a big believer in the usefulness of "helpers" as they can create global ambiguity.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for your answer. As my application going more complex, codes in controller also becoming tumid, do you know how to reduce the codes in controller if I do not move them the helper file ?

Comment: Probably one of the most useful blog posts for SRP design patterns in rails http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  your module like that, you have to call is_c on an instance. This means that you will have to include DisplayHelper in the class associated with that instance.

if you don't want to call it on an instance, then you can define is_c on the SELF:

Try this:

```
 module DisplayHelper
        def self.is_c
          a + b
        end
end
```

In the controller:

> ```
> DisplayHelper.is_c
> ```

If you don't understand just comment and i'll try to explain. I hope all of that makes sense.